# how to generate qr code image, with vcf file ios

Tags: ios, xcode, qr-code, zxing

i have contact details as string

```
    BEGIN:VCARD
    VERSION:3.0
    N:Doe;John
    FN:John Doe
    ORG:Company
    TITLE:CEO
   ADR;TYPE=WORK:;;1234 Any Street;Beverly Hills;CA;90210;USA
   TEL;TYPE=WORK,VOICE:1-555-555-4321
   TEL;TYPE=CELL,VOICE:1-555-555-1234
    EMAIL;TYPE=PREF,INTERNET:johndoe@yourcompany.com
   URL;TYPE=WORK:http://yourcompany.com
   END:VCARD
```

how to make qr code image with above mention information, programmatically.

Comment: which api you are using for generating qrcode?

Comment: i am not using any api upto now, but if there is any(free of cost), by using i can have solution. i am willing to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i ended up find my own solution,using Zxing libary

```
       ZXMultiFormatWriter *writer = [ZXMultiFormatWriter writer];


NSString *str=@"BEGIN:VCARD\r\nVERSION:2.1\r\nN:Satya;Dash;;;\r\nADR;DOM;PARCEL;HOME:;;****Mission Street;Cuttack City;Orissa;94014;INDIA.\r\nEMAIL;INTERNET:satya@domain.com\r\nTEL;CELL:22-122-4567\r\nTEL;CELL:133-156-3345\r\nEND:VCARD";
ZXBitMatrix* result = [writer encode:str
                              format:kBarcodeFormatQRCode
                               width:320
                              height:300
                               error:&error];
if (result) {
    UIImage* uiImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:[[ZXImage imageWithMatrix:result] cgimage]];
    [self.imageView setImage:uiImage];
    [self.lbl setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",str]];

} else {
    NSString *errorMessage = [error localizedDescription];
    NSLog(@"error is %@",errorMessage);
}
```

when you will scan qr image it will return vcard version 2.1

Answer (score 0):

I m using codeignitor for this.This is the library link (https://github.com/dwisetiyadi/CodeIgniter-PHP-QR-Code).i insert a short url in this.generated by yourls(yourls.org/#API).when user scans the code.mobile ask to open the link and when user opens the link.i take him to my webpage where whole qr code vcf information is shown link name address etc and a download button.when user click on download button (.vcf) file is gets download which can be used in mobile as well as outlook.